# Widgets wont Show Up

Tags: python, windows, tkinter

im trying to make a very simple app, so  the concept is: i have a main window, and inside the window i want have 2 frames which are Options Frame and Content Frame, so the Options Frame will contain Buttons, when a button is clicked, the content in Content Frame will change. My problem is, buttons on def create_options_frame wont show up, but i don't get any error message, please help ,me

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter import messagebox

class MainWindow(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.geometry('800x300')
        self.title('Catatanku')

class OptionsView(ttk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master, **kw):
        super().__init__(master, **kw)

        self.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.grid_columnconfigure(1, weight=1)

        self.create_options_frame().grid(row=0, column=0, sticky='wns')
        self.create_content_frame().grid(row=0, column=1)

    def create_options_frame(self) -> ttk.Frame:
        self.options_frame = ttk.Frame(self )
        btn_buat_catatan = tk.Button(self.options_frame, text='Buat Catatan', font=('Times new roman', 16))
        btn_buat_catatan.pack(fill=tk.BOTH, expand=True)

        btn_buka_catatan = tk.Button(self.options_frame, text='Buka Catatan', font=('Times new roman', 16))
        btn_buka_catatan.pack(fill=tk.BOTH, expand=True)

        return self.options_frame 
        

    def create_content_frame(self) -> ttk.Frame:
        self.content_frame = ttk.Frame(self)
        return self.content_frame


if __name__=='__main__':
    root = tk.Tk()
    root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 2):

I think what you need is:

- create instance of `MainWindow` instead of `tk.Tk`
- create instance of `OptionsView` inside `MainWindow`

```py
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

class MainWindow(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.geometry('800x300')
        self.title('Catatanku')

        # create instance of OptionsView
        self.view = OptionsView(self)
        self.view.pack(fill="both", expand=1)

class OptionsView(ttk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master, **kw):
        super().__init__(master, **kw)

        self.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.grid_columnconfigure(1, weight=1)

        self.create_options_frame().grid(row=0, column=0, sticky='wns')
        self.create_content_frame().grid(row=0, column=1)

    def create_options_frame(self) -> ttk.Frame:
        self.options_frame = ttk.Frame(self)
        btn_buat_catatan = tk.Button(self.options_frame, text='Buat Catatan', font=('Times new roman', 16))
        btn_buat_catatan.pack(fill=tk.BOTH, expand=True)

        btn_buka_catatan = tk.Button(self.options_frame, text='Buka Catatan', font=('Times new roman', 16))
        btn_buka_catatan.pack(fill=tk.BOTH, expand=True)

        return self.options_frame


    def create_content_frame(self) -> ttk.Frame:
        self.content_frame = ttk.Frame(self)
        return self.content_frame


if __name__=='__main__':
    # create instance of MainWindow instead of tk.Tk
    root = MainWindow()
    root.mainloop()
```